# Install IOTOP/IOSTAT via ZYPPER (or anything else) on a SUSE (SLES) 12 Virual Machine (HyperV)

Tags: virtual-machine, sles, zypper, iostat, hyper-v

I have a virtual machine hosted on HyperV. It is a SUSE Enterprise 12 OS residing in a rack somewhere in the dark side of our office.
This machine is under-performing during a certain load that takes a few hours to complete. I could REXEC the CPU and RAM but couldn't see any anomalies.
I am now looking into the possibility of an IO bottleneck and would like to poll the machine for disk reads/writes every 1 minute. However, it seems to have no "in the box" facilities to do that.

I looked up IOtop and IOstat and it looks like this is what I want but they are not recognized on this machine (not installed). When I did the recommended "zypper in iotop", the machine responded:
File '/content' not found on medium 'dir:///mnt'

That's where my linux knowledge ends. Tried to google it but could not find a way to install what I want.

Will very much appreciate your input here!
P.S: I have full rights on that machine

Comment: make sure all needed repositories are enabled

Answer (score 2):

The correct package to install `iostat` would be `sysstat`. So if you run:

```
zypper in sysstat iotop
```

this would install the `iostat` and `iotop` tools.

Anyway, the error you receive is, that you haven't (virtually) inserted the product DVD (image) into the virtual machine.